# Creating a view with a column not in the base table

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with 4 columns.  I am being asked to create a view that performs a calculation and then puts the results in a column not in the table.

Here it is: Create a view called v_count that shows the number of students working on each assignment. The view should have columns for the assignment number and the count.

The underlying table does not have a count column.

Comment: What effort have you made?

Comment: Hi I should have posted my work and I apologize for not doing so. Sorry about that, I will do so from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to make use of `Count` function and `GROUP BY` clause. Suppose you have student id and assignment id in your table:

```
sId AsnId
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   5
2   8
3   2
3   4
```

Then following query will give you count of students working on an assignments:

```
SELECT asnId [Assignment], COUNT(sid) [Students] 
FROM Assignment 
GROUP BY asnid
```

Now you can use this query to create your view. But do read docs about `Count` and `Group By`

Comment: you are welcome but as @mark leiber commented on question, please do make an effort and then tell us what did not work